# How to serialize a list of tuples in marshmallow?

Tags: python, marshmallow

I'm trying to serialize a dict which has a list of tuples nested within:

```
positive_explanation = fields.Dict(fields.List(tuple((fields.Integer(), fields.Float())), required=True))
```

but when I try to I get this error:

```
ValueError: The instances of the list elements must be of type marshmallow.base.FieldABC
```

I have also tried:

```
positive_explanation = fields.Dict(fields.List(fields.Tuple((fields.Integer(), fields.Float())), required=True))
```

which returned this error instead:

```
AttributeError: module 'marshmallow.fields' has no attribute 'Tuple'
```

The API docs have me quite confused. What is the correct way to nest a list of tuples?

Comment: fields.Tuple is added in 3.rc versions.

Comment: I've tried `fields.Tuple` as described in my example above, but it still shows an error. Any idea why it's not working ?

Comment: you are using version 2.x. fields.Tuple is added in version 3

Comment: I have version 3.0.0b16 installed

Comment: :D my bad, but still yours' version is older than the one in fields.Tuple implemented  https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/changelog.html?highlight=tuple#rc4-2019-02-08. you at least need to have 3.0.rc4 installed